# FullAdder - subtraction - overflow indication

Tags: digital-logic

I have a true table of full adder. Now i want to complete the adder so that it can also used used for subtraction (with overflow indicator). (OF = XYS'+ X'Y's)

```
x y cin --- cout s
0 0 0   ---   0  0
0 0 1   ---   0  1
0 1 0   ---   0  1
0 1 1   ---   1  0
1 0 0   ---   1  1
1 0 1   ---   1  0
1 1 0   ---   1  0
1 1 1   ---   1  1
```

cout = xy + xc + yc
s = x'y'c+ x'yc'+ xy'c'+ xyc

I was thinking that the true table for subtraction will be like this :

```
sub s x y --- overflow
0   0 0 0 --- 0
0   0 0 1 --- 0
0   0 1 0 --- 0
0   0 1 1 --- 1
0   1 0 0 --- 1
0   1 0 1 --- 0
0   1 1 0 --- 0
0   1 1 1 --- 0
```

is this table right ?

or i need to use this one

```
0   0 0 0 --- 0
0   0 0 1 --- 0
0   0 1 0 --- 0
0   0 1 1 --- 1    === can any one explain why i got 1 in the overflow here?
0   1 0 0 --- 1
0   1 0 1 --- 0
0   1 1 0 --- 0
0   1 1 1 --- 0
1   0 0 0 --- 0
1   0 0 1 --- 0
1   0 1 0 --- 1                  is this the correct true table ?
1   0 1 1 --- 0
1   1 0 0 --- 0
1   1 0 1 --- 1
1   1 1 0 --- 0
1   1 1 1 --- 0
```

Is this true table correct with the function (of = overflow) OF = XYS'+ X'Y's
How to make AU for this one ?
Need help plz